# Parameters for elliptic curve prime192v3

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm looking all over the internet for prime192v3's parameters. I think I may have found them [here](http://bouncycastle.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.32/jdk1_80_2org_2bouncycastle_2asn1_2x9_2X962NamedCurves_8java-source.html), but it doesn't say what variable each number matches to. Is there some central place where I can find this information?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the constructors and see which values correspond to which parameters.

The ECCurveFp reference is [here](http://bouncycastle.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.32/classorg_1_1bouncycastle_1_1math_1_1ec_1_1ECCurve_1_1Fp.html)

Note that $P$ is given in decimal

$P = \texttt{6277101735386680763835789423207666416083908700390324961279}$

$a = \texttt{fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffffffffffffc}$

$b = \texttt{22123dc2395a05caa7423daeccc94760a7d462256bd56916}$

The X9ECParameters reference is [here](http://bouncycastle.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.32/classorg_1_1bouncycastle_1_1asn1_1_1x9_1_1X9ECParameters.html)

Note that $G$ is in compressed form

$G = \texttt{027d29778100c65a1da1783716588dce2b8b4aee8e228f1896}$

$n = \texttt{ffffffffffffffffffffffff7a62d031c83f4294f640ec13}$

$h = \texttt{1}$

$seed = \texttt{c469684435deb378c4b65ca9591e2a5763059a2e}$